# React Native receiving sensor data?

Tags: ios, swift, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I have a device that sends data to a sdk at about 250 events a second. I am planning on hook that up to React Native to receive the packets and plot them on a graph.

I read that the slowest part of react native is the bridge, but couldn't find benchmarks or anything so I am wondering if it would even be able to handle this many events over the bridge. I have a few possible work arounds but wanted to see if anyone has faced something like this.

My next challenge, if this is possible, is to plot the data using some library. If anyone has thoughts on that i'd be interested in hearing that as well.

Thanks!

Comment: what do you want? it's very confusing.